# ¿Cómo hace pandas para imprimir una serie inmediatamente después de crearla?

Tags: python, pandas

Mi pregunta gira en torno a lo siguiente:
Cuando creo una serie, pandas automáticamente la imprime:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
    0    1
    1    2
    2    3
    3    4
    dtype: int64`
```

Cuando por estar construida de una clase `Series()` yo esperaría que la salida sea como la siguiente:

```
>>> type(pd.Series([1,2,3,4]))
     <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

A manera de curiosidad pregunto: ¿Cómo lo hace?

Comment: nop, nunca te la imprime. Aunque esto depende de si estas trabajando con un editor de código, IDE o con Juper notebook o google colab

Comment: Por cierto en python todo es un objeto por lo que todo tiene un clase y nunca la salida es de tipo `<class ...>` ese es el tipo de dato lo cual es muy diferente al valor contenido en el. En una serie de pandas el valor es simplemente lo que le hayas asignado a la serie y listo

Comment: Exactamente la metaclase `type` te lo dice "type" que significa "tipo" y sirve para ver el tipo de dato. Nunca obtendrás como salida la clase del objeto a menos que se la pidas

Answer (score 2):

Aqui hay un par de conceptos que se están confundiendo:

1. Lo que ves por pantalla no sale como consecuencia de haber creado la `Series`, sino como consecuencia de que al crearse el objeto, se retorna ese objeto y el shell interactivo siempre muestra el resultado de la operación.

   En el fondo esto es como si en el intérprete pones:

   ```
   >>> math.sqrt(25)
   5.0
   ```

   No es que la función imprima nada, sino que ha retornado el resultado, y **el interprete muestra siempre el resultado** de la última operación realizada.
2. Para ello el intérprete no sabe de antemano cómo debe mostrar cada posible tipo de dato, por lo que **delega** esa funcionalidad en el propio objeto que se está mostrando. Cuando el intérprete llega a que es necesario mostrar el objeto `x`, lo que hace es invocar `x.__repr__()`. Este método es el responsable de retornar una cadena de caracteres que será lo que el intérprete mostrará.

   Si `x` no define el método `__repr__()`, entonces el intérprete usará el método `.__str__()`

Python por defecto no muestra nada por el mero hecho de haberlo computado. Eso lo hace cuando trabajas en el intérprete interactivo, pero no cuando escribes un programa. En este caso debes usar `print(x)`. La función `print()` entonces usará `x.__str__()` para obtener la representación en forma de cadena que será lo que finalmente se imprimirá.

Cuando implementas tu propia clase, puedes proporcionar tu implementación de `_-repr__()` o de `__str__()`. Si no lo haces heredarás de la clase `object` la implementación que hace Python. Es esa implementación la que muestra el famoso `<__main__.Class_X object at 0x7f10445a52b0>`

Naturalmente Pandas sí que implementa estos métodos en sus clases, de modo que hace posible que un simple `print(df)` te muestre una representación amigable del dataframe, o que en el intérprete interactivo puedas volcar una variable y verla correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Propiamente `pandas.Series` no imprime el texto. Los modulos de python utilizan métodos para cada accion que les hagas.

Para que al crear un objeto `pandas.Series` y que imprima un texto, debería ser especificado en el 'constructor' '___init__'  [[doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#constructor)].

Puedes revisar manualmente el código del modulo de pandas en donde se ubica python.exe (usar: `print(pd.__file__)` [[ver fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42747425/13636459)]), o usando `help(pd.Series.__init__)` que muestra el 'docstring' en caso de que incluya esa información.

Para que te hagas una idea, mira el siguiente código:

```py
import pandas as pd

class NewSeries(pd.Series):
    def __init__ (self,list):
        super().__init__(list)
        print("Esto es tipo: {}".format(type(self)))

NewSeries([1,2,3,4])
```

Se usa el mismo constructor 'original' de *panda.Series* pero adicionalmente se agrega *print(message)*. Esto genera la salida inmediatamente la creas.

Output: `Esto es tipo: <class '__main__.NewSeries'>`

Así se haría, pero **El modulo de pandas no incluye 'print' en el constructor**, la prueba es que, si ejecutas el código en la 'shell'/consola de python, no generará ninguna salida. Así que la opción más razonable para que eso suceda es que un IDE externo (o el jupyter notebook) esté programado de tal forma que al final de cada ejecución de bloque ejecute automáticamente:

`print(*última_linea_de_código*)`

Cuya función sería mostrar en consola lo que entrega la última linea de código.

**Nota:** Para que 'print(*objeto*)' funcione tiene que tener declarado '_*str_*'. En el ejemplo lo hereda de 'pd.Series'. El print que se ha puesto como ejemplo en el método '_*init_*' bien podría ir solo en '_*str_*'.